# The tag is not well formed in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am rather new to Javascript so can anyone please help me on this?

I have a link button inside gridview where I have called a javascript inside it but am getting the error that the tag is not well formed.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Style="color: #333333" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick= "return '<%# "Newf(" + Eval("NoOfQuestionnaires").ToString() + ");"%>'" Text="Delete" />
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: can you show us how the html looks on the client side?

Comment: What I mean is, open that page up in a browser. Then view the source and give us the generated html of the button

Comment: Wonder if me answer helped you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is beeing formatted in a wrong way.

It's a better aproach use a *format* when using `Eval` like you did, it's more clear to understand:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" 
    runat="server" 
    Style="color: #333333" 
    CausesValidation="false" 
    CommandName="Delete" 
    OnClientClick= '<%#Eval("NoOfQuestionnaires", " return Newf({0});") %>' 
    Text="Delete" />
```

**Edit**

Just remember that `{0}` will be changed with your variable value so if it is a string you need to use quotes.

**Edit 2**

Your code didn't work because the `Eval` tags need to be place in the property value with nothing else. You merge some string and the `Eval` value.

More than that, `Eval` needs to be place inside a property value with single quotes so the closest way you could do is like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="btnDelete" 
    runat="server" 
    Style="color: #333333" 
    CausesValidation="false" 
    CommandName="Delete" 
    OnClientClick='<%# "return Newf(" + Eval("NoOfQuestionnaires").ToString() + ");"%>' 
    Text="Delete" />
```